# Python string comparsion

Tags: python, regex

I want to compare the 2 strings whether it matches or not.

Lets say:

```
>>> s1 = "I am s1 H1"
>>> s2 = "IAmS1 H1"
>>> 
>>> if s1 == s2:
...     print "s1 and s2 are equal"
... else:
...     print "s1 and s2 not equal"
... 
I am getting OUTPUT: s1 and s2 not equal

My expected OUTPUT : s1 and s2 are equal
```

I tried with removing spaces and keeping the string as lowercase. It works, But I believe, its not a good solution

**my intention is 2 strings char should match each other, irrespective of white spaces and upper or lower cases**

Only solution is Regular-Expressions ? or any other solutions ? Please post your ideas and views. It would be really appreciable

Comment: your output is correct

Comment: @Michael Hej, What if s1 string has same len as s2 with different chars ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to use regex, then you may try the below.

```
>>> s1 = "I am s1 H1"
>>> s2 = "IAmS1 H1"
>>> if re.match(r'(?i)'+re.sub(r'\s', '', s1)+r'$', re.sub(r'\s', '', s2)):
        print('Equal')


Equal
```

`\s` matches any kind of whitespace. You could also use `[ \t]` instead of `\s`. `(?i)` case-insensitive modifier. Since `re.match` tries to match from the beginning of the string, you don't need to include start of the line anchor `^` and you must include the end of the line anchor `$`.

Comment: The regex module has a flag re.IGNORECASE or re.I which would make it more readable than the (?i), however.

Comment: but your code is not working if s1 = "I Am here", s2 = "iaMHerE"

Comment: @vamsi guess you should stick with non re approach.This will not work if string are like `s1 = "I \am s1 H1"
s2 = "I\AmS1 H1"` .

Comment: @vks both  won't work because `\a` will turn to `\x07`

Comment: @AvinashRaj not when it is in `raw mode`.

Comment: @vks you made an invalid point here. Both answers won't work in that case.yep it's better to stick with a non Regex solution for this case. Don't ask op like don't accept this answer. He knows which one is to accept and which one is not. Better and best answer suits this question will automatically get up votes.

Comment: @vamsi accept an answer which you likes the most don't hear to anyone and I don't care about accepts.

Answer (score 6):

You haven't explained what you expect of "a match", but judging by your example, I would say you can simply do that:

```
if s1.lower().replace(" ","") == s2.lower().replace(" ",""):
```

It will effectively ignore spaces and case. If it's not what you were looking for, please refine your question.

If you're interested in removing all whitespaces, then you could use this instead:

```
if "".join(s1.lower().split()) == "".join(s2.lower().split()):
```

Comment: my intention is 2 strings char should match each other, irrespective of white spaces and upper or lower cases

Comment: Then this is the only way to do it. Of course, you can extract that test in a function if you call it in different places. There is no need nor reason to use regex here.

Comment: @vermillon: but your code is not working if s1 = "I Am here",  s2 = "iaMHerE"

Comment: I need to wake up, indeed... Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

So it looks like you want to ignore white space and whether characters are upper or lower case.

If that's the case, you would use something like:

```
s1 = "I am s1 H1"
s2 = "IAmS1 H1"
if s1.replace(" ","").lower() == s2.replace(" ","").lower():
    print("equal")
```

Although, given how ugly your code will look if you pepper it with lots of statements like that, you may want to refactor it out to a function:

```
def strEqualSpecial(p1,p2):
    return p1.replace(" ","").lower() == p2.replace(" ","").lower()

s1 = "I am s1 H1"
s2 = "IAmS1 H1"
if strEqualSpecial(s1,s2):
    print("equal")
```

Then you restrict the "ugliness" to a small proportion of your code, leaving the rest of it relatively clean. This will also make things easier should you decide to change the rules later on, such as ignoring *all* white-space rather than just spaces:

```
import re
def strEqualSpecial(p1,p2):
    return re.sub("\s+","",p1.lower()) == re.sub("\s+","",p2.lower())
```